# How do I setup ubiquiti Nanostation M5?

Tags: networking, ubiquiti

I connected my two NanoStation M5 devices as outlined in the manual. Now I want to login to admin and do the setup but I do not see a related ubiquiti SSID to connect to, to enable me to login to Admin via 192.168.1.20? Am I suppose to see an SSID?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the NanoStations are set up to be a point to point bridge, they won't also act as wireless access points.  You'll need to connect the ethernet port on one of the devices to your network.

Note that if the devices came as a pair, they may not require any additional configuration.